# WKWebview and web content restrictions

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, restriction

I have a very specific issue with the wkwebview. When a user opts to use the  `Settings / Screen Time / Content Restrictions / web content / Allowed Websites Only` then the user will be presented with a Native ui component which says `Restricted Site` and gives the user an option to allow the website via a `Allow website` button. The problem is that the website exception is indeed added to allowed list in setting but the following action of the button is blocked.

```
[Process] 0x10781e618 - [pageProxyID=8, webPageID=9, PID=6619] WebPageProxy::Ignoring request to load this main resource because it was handled by content filter
```

That means the user is stuck on the screen, which of cause is not ideal. To solve this we added an alert with the option to return to the login page (better messaging is  required).

I have tried all `WKNavigationDelegate` and `WKUIDelegate` hooks which are not trigger upon clicking on the `Allow Website` button and I could not find any documentation around that feature. I guess the only way is to educate the user by showing a dialog with instruction to add a bunch of urls to the allowed sites section of `screen time` and then restart the app or reload the webview via the dialog. The whole process seems very clunky.

If anyone has some more information about this it would highly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Turns out that screen time has 2 ways of dealing with restricted content. **With** or **without** a passcode. If a passcode is set upon clicking the `allow website` button you will open a `enter passcode` dialog, which will reload the webview when entered correctly. If you don't have a passcode set the webview will **not reload**. In my answer below I was using a javascript to reload the webview after the html button was clicked (the shown view is not native but a local html file.) The problem with that approach is that it will crash the the app if a passcode is set.
I was hoping to find a way to know if the passcode screen has been presented but I was not successful yet. If I had that information then I could stop the webview from reloading and therefor stop the crash.

Answer (score 0):

I have been learning more about this, and as it turns out the screen which shows the `Restricted Site` message isn't a native component but rather a system html file which gets loaded into the webview.

```
file:///System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/ContentFilterBlockedPage.html
```

The `Allow website` link  contains a href of `x-apple-content-filter://unblock` which when clicked will add the blocked site to the allowed websites list (it seems to be handled outside of the WKNavigationDelegate scope). In order to refresh the webview, you need to inject a small javascript which reloads the page after you clicked the link.

```js
(function(){
    const element = document.querySelector('#unblock a');
    console.log("####unblock####");
    console.log("ELEMENTS", element);
    if (element) {
        element.onclick = function() {

            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("called message handler")
                callMessageHandler("reloadWebView")
            }, 1000);
        };
    }
})();
```

You can use the userscript messageHandler functionality to reload the url, my example is incomplete but its not hard to work this out.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: There are more intricacies to this. Screen time allows you to set a passcode if you choose a passcode the code above is called while the password prompt is open. If you now enter the passcode or cancel the prompt the app will crash. The most interesting thing is that after the passcode has been entered the webview reloads by itself (without the js, commented the onclick handler). I reckon that this the expected behaviour but its buggy. Thanks apple.  I am not sure how to fix this.